# In Need of Advice for Making a DIY S'mores Costume

Tags: costume-design

I am planning to make a DIY S'mores costume, and I was wondering if anyone had advice on what spray paint color would match the color of a graham cracker. Any input and or advice regarding this would be much appreciated! Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi Jack, have you tried bringing a Graham cracker to a store where they sell spray paints and just compare colours? That seems to me the best option, especially if you have a good understanding of colour mixing. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benjamin Moore makes spray paint in the shade 1113 Graham Cracker. I think that will be your best option.

Comment: Thanks so much @Kkell1150!